# Error in execution of Apache nutch-2.2.1

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, nutch

I have installed Nutch 2.2.1 in Ubuntu 12.04 but on executing the command 
./nutch crawl urls/ -dir download/ -depth 3 -topN 5

I get the following error:-

InjectorJob: Using class org.apache.gora.memory.store.MemStore as the Gora storage class.
InjectorJob: total number of urls rejected by filters: 0
InjectorJob: total number of urls injected after normalization and filtering: 0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: job failed: name=generate: null, jobid=job_local1165582916_0002
    at org.apache.nutch.util.NutchJob.waitForCompletion(NutchJob.java:54)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.GeneratorJob.run(GeneratorJob.java:199)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler.runTool(Crawler.java:68)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler.run(Crawler.java:152)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler.run(Crawler.java:250)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler.main(Crawler.java:257)

Answer (score 3):

Command /bin/nutch crawl is deprecated. You should use /bin/crawl instead.